Issue with fetch in Next.js middleware: [TypeError: fetch failed] with cause [Error: AggregateError] when calling localhost:3333
I'm encountering an issue when making a fetch request inside a middleware in my Next.js application. When I try to fetch data from localhost:3333, I get the following error: [TypeError: fetch failed] { cause: [Error: AggregateError] }
// Don't work
const responseA = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST!}/auth/user`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => console.log(error))

console.log(responseA)

// Work
const responseB = await fetch("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=postman")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => console.log(error))

console.log(responseB)

I’m using this fetch request to verify if the user is authenticated when they attempt to access routes that require authentication. By checking the response from the localhost:3333/auth/user endpoint, I determine whether the user is logged in or not. If the user is authenticated, they’re allowed to proceed; otherwise, they’re redirected to the login page.
Front : localhost:3000
Back: localhost:3333
Thank you for your help
Resolved: The issue is now resolved. In fact, I was making HTTP requests to http://localhost:3333, but since I am using Docker, the container executing the request did not have a web server running on port 3333.
Instead of using localhost, I realized I needed to use the name of the container that contains the web server. This allowed the request to route correctly to the container running the web service, and everything is now working as expected.
